# I am using the query block and what I want and see on the editor page is not the same with the actual results

Tags: posts, query

I want my posts to be just as the first picture on a grid formation but when I save and view the page it shows otherwise.

[image: On the Editor]

[image: On the Site]

Comment: Are you using your own theme? Where are you adding this block and where are you viewing it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.